# Module Federation (Unexpected token '!==' main.js:619)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

When I try to get a remote container and show it component on the web page I got an error - Unexpected token '!==' main.js:619 . I tried to update some packages related with webpack, but it isn't help. Had anyone this problem or knows how to resolve it?

I leave the my code [here](https://github.com/Vladislav-Lukyanuk/module-federation)

[image]

Comment: something is missing there. that is invalid javascript

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: yes. it's a really invalid js code but it's self generated here. I gave you more... check this link please https://github.com/Vladislav-Lukyanuk/module-federation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue inside the webpack core, after a lot of times of investigation.  It accepts the remote address that contains remote container name and server full path.

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
  remotes: {
    home: "home@http://localhost:3001/remoteEntry.js",
    nav: "nav@http://localhost:3003/remoteEntry.js",
  }
}),
```